# Implementing pagination in a Ruby on Rails 4 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an API on Rails using ActiveRecordSerializer for serialization. When I want to render a list of resources I use:

```
render json: @resources
```

This automatically detects that there is a serializer for the resource, and uses it.

Now I want to implement pagination, and my idea is having a class called PaginatedResponse, instantiate it and render it as a json like this:

```
render json: PaginatedResponse.new(@resources, <more meta information of the page>)
```

The problem is that when I use this, everything works well but the resources are not rendered using ActiveRecordSerializer, but a default serializer. I suspect that this is happening because PaginatedResponse does not extend ActiveRecord.

Any clue how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was including ActiveModel::SerializerSupport in PaginatedResponse to indicate ActiveRecordSerializer that a serializer should be used.

Comment: I need a similar solution, can you post some code examples of your PaginatedResponse class and the serializers you used.  I can't seem to figure out how to get the root of my object array to reflect my resource class. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 has introduced a new concept jbuilder by default. So just create index.json.jbuilder and put the json syntex based code. Just refer the default scaffold index json jbuilder below,

```
json.array!(@users) do |user|
  json.extract! user, :name, :email, :phone, :native_place
  json.url user_url(user, format: :json)
end
```

This is for rendering all users with his name, phone, native_place.
So remove the line

```
render json: @resources
```

from your code and implement the the new jbuilder concept.